# How to understand and model Causal Inference from regression?

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, causality

I'm fairly new to casual inferences. I know that regression is used to identify linear relationship between the dependent and independent variables and it doesn't necessarily mean causality.

I have recently come across some quasi experimental methods such as Diff-in-Diff and PSM methods which use regression to identify causal relationships.

I tired to go through some online articles about this and got to know that zero conditional mean assumption, the error term has zero mean given any value of explanator variable is crucial for causal inference. I'll be honest, I am having a hard time understanding this assumption.

Currently I'm having a disconnect on what assumptions/conditions makes regression model identify causal vs linear relations.

Can anyone please help me understand the following:

- Differences in assumptions in setting up regression for linear vs causality? (What's the zero conditional mean assumption in simple terms(with an example if possible)?
- How to come up with good confounding variables for setting up regression model to identify causality? (Do we need to look at any distributions/ perform any tests etc)?

Also, please provide some useful links if there are any good articles available on this topic.

Comment: A lot is related to exogeneity of error assumption. Read about Snow’s work on cholera in London. It is a fun read and very educational in terms of causal inference. You can also lookup this year Nobel laureate Angrist’s paper on unemployment related to natural experiment in New Jersey but it is not as much fun

Comment: Confounding variables aren't your only worry... there's also selection bias, the fact that "controlling for a variable" can actually *add* confounding bias, and issues with differential measurement error, among other worries. If you have time for a textbook or two, I would suggest Pearl, J. (2000). *Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference*. Cambridge University Press., and Hernán, M. A., & Robins, J. M. (2020). [*Causal Inference: What If*](https://www.hsph.harvard.edu/miguel-hernan/causal-inference-book/). Chapman & Hall/CRC.

Comment: I would recommend *The Book of Why* and *Causal Inference in Statistics: A Primer*, before tackling *Causality: Models, Reasoning, and Inference.*

Comment: Thanks @aksakal

Comment: Thanks aksakal, alexis and adrian, I have found the causal inference what if very helpful in understanding the use of regression both for association and causality.